# Смысловые отношения между частями сложносочиненного предложения

Tags: грамматика, ссп

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, **как определять смысловые отношения между частями сложносочиненного предложения?**
Соединительные союзы: одновременность действий, последовательность действий, причинно-следственные отношения.
Проблема с причинно-следственными отношениями.

Пример 1. *Усталое солнце уходило от мира, спокойно пропылав свой полдень и утро; и угасающий день пленительно и ярко румянился.*

Пример 2. *Зубинский и моторист раскачивали погруженный в песок катер, Рогозин тоже навалился всем телом на борт.*

Пример 3. *Вдруг все это скользнет с яблони  — и тень упадет по всей аллее.*

Пример 4. *В саду горит костер, и крепко тянет душистым дымом вишневых сучьев.*

Как определить, есть ли **четкое** определение?
Противительные союзы: сопоставление и противопоставление.

Пример. *Там на поляне немного светлее, а над головой белеет Млечный Путь.*
Это сопоставление? **Как** это определить?

Answer (score 1):

Смысловые отношения и определяются по смыслу.Какое ещё чёткое определение Вы хотите? И потом, смысловые отношения бывают не очень ясными, совмещаются разные оттенки.

Пример 1. Усталое солнце уходило от мира, спокойно пропылав свой полдень и утро; и угасающий день пленительно и ярко румянился. Солнце уходило, оно устало,потому и день угасал и румянился от солнца, а не пылал, как в полдень. - причинно-следственные связи.

Пример 2. Зубинский и моторист раскачивали погруженный в песок катер, Рогозин тоже навалился всем телом на борт. -последовательные действия с оттенком причинно-следственных связей. Навалился он, увидев, что они раскачивают. Одновременных действий не может быть, потому что в первом предложении сказуемое - глагол несов. вида, а во втором совершенного.

Пример 3. Вдруг все это скользнет с яблони - и тень упадет по всей аллее. - причинно-следств. связи. Тень упала, потому что что-то соскользнуло с яблони.

Пример 4. В саду горит костер, и крепко тянет душистым дымом вишневых сучьев. - одновременные события с оттенком причинно-следственных связей. Дымом тянет, потому что горит костёр.

Пример. Там на поляне немного светлее, а над головой белеет Млечный Путь.-сопоставление, союз противительный, но одно другое не исключает, противопоставления нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема в том, что определения нет. А в работе надо однозначно поставить отношение, совмещение оттенков разных указать нельзя.