# Причинно-следственные отношения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, семантика

Есть ли смысловая разница между этими примерами?

Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь (основное высказывание содержится в первой части, во второй указывается причина). – На улице проливной дождь – выйти невозможно (причина указывается в первой части, во второй следствие, вывод, что составляет основу высказывания).

Из объяснения Розенталя, только ясно,что местами поменялись причина и следствие.А смысл поменялся?

С примерами ниже смысл изменился. Нельзя же сказать по аналогии с примерами ниже: выйти невозможно -  на улице проливной дождь **(выйти невозможно,поэтому проливной дождь)**

Ср. также при сохранении того же порядка частей бессоюзного сложного предложения: Молодёжь ушла: на вечере стало скучно (ушла, потому что стало скучно). Молодёжь ушла – на вечере стало скучно (ушла, поэтому стало скучно).

Comment: Полезные ссылки: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427881/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430614/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5/430630#430630

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430196/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8b/430198#430198

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, но в них нет ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас ошибка в знаке, нужно: " Нельзя же сказать по аналогии с примерами ниже: выйти невозможно - на улице проливной дождь (выйти невозможно,поэтому проливной дождь)" Да или нет?.

Comment: @Arina, да, вы правы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысловая разница небольшая, но всё-таки есть.

***Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь.***

Объект по определённой причине не может выполнить конкретное действие, хотя действие может быть желательным, направленным.

***На улице проливной дождь – выйти невозможно.***

Констатируется факт и делается  вывод, что действие в принципе невозможно, ситуация статична.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а какой смысловой оттенок содержится в таком предложении: Выйти невозможно - на улице проливной дождь.

Comment: Да, Екатерина, если честно, я тоже не понял, что вы имеете в виду, говоря: "Объект по определённой причине не может выполнить конкретное действие...."

Comment: Мне, кстати, понятна мысль, просто она сформулирована сложновато. Некто решил прогуляться, а на улице дождь, выйти невозможно. А во втором случае он просто выглянул в окно и увидел, что дождь сильный, в такой и из дома не выйдешь .Но  может, он и не собирался никуда выходить.

Comment: Выйти невозможно - на улице проливной дождь. Такое предложение (с тире) очень сложно понять и принять. Вот если части поменять местами, тогда да, смысл становится понятным.

Comment: У Розенталя части поменяты. Но смысл изменился?

Comment: Екатерина, сейчас я внимательно прочитал ваш ответ. Думаю, вы правы. Смысл изменился, но незначительно. Спасибо!

Comment: Екатерина, сегодня уже допускается в таких предложениях вместо двоеточия тире . Вот что говорится в справочнике Лопатина:

Comment: Примечание 2. В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, ***причины***, обоснования, изъяснения ***допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике)***. Вот, в частности, примеры из произведений К. Паустовского: ***На молу погасили огни — теплоход ушел;Паханов крепко держал капитана за локоть — капитан был еще слаб после ранения;В армию меня тоже не берут — сердце заштопанное.***

Comment: А мне предложение с тире "Выйти невозможно - на улице проливной дождь" кажется вполне естественным. Это присоединительная конструкция, универсальная, с разными оттенками значений. Что касается двоеточия, то  это всегда  остановка в речи, возвращение к сказанному, объяснение ранее сказанного - в общем, довольно неуклюжая конструкция. Недаром тире активно вытесняет двоеточие, особенно при выражении причинно-следственных отношений. Двоеточие  хорошо только для раскрытия содержания ранее названной темы, то есть при значении пояснения.  Особенно двоеточие    не смотрится в коротких предложениях.

Answer (score 3):

(1)Выйти невозможно (?) (2) на улице проливной дождь.

Нет сомнения, что предложение (1)  – это следствие, а предложение (2)  – это причина. Эти отношения мы можем выразить при любом порядке предложений:

**(1) Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь** (следствие и причина, двоеточие).

**(2) На улице проливной дождь  – выйти невозможно** (причина и следствие, тире должно обозначать разделительные отношения). Только вот отношения эти на разделительные не похожи, те выглядят примерно так: **Будет сильный дождь  – гулять не пойдем.** В нашем же примере отношения **присоединительные,** они, кстати, могут говорить не о желании выйти, а о силе дождя. Присоединение часто содержит **дополнительную информацию.**

Но мы знаем, что  двоеточие можно заменить тире. Тогда: **Выйти невозможно  – на улице проливной дождь.** Отношения не изменились (следствие и причина), только  тире здесь присоединительное, а не разделительное,  то есть нет резкого деления на две части. И читается предложение почти так же, как при двоеточии, именно поэтому варианты взаимозаменяемы.

**Пример из Розенталя:**

Молодежь ушла: в клубе стало скучно. Следствие и причина, двоеточие.

Молодежь ушла  – в клубе стало скучно. Причина и следствие, разделительное тире.

Замена двоеточия тире: Молодежь ушла  – в клубе стало скучно. Следствие и причина, присоединительное тире.

Получается, что при постановке тире мы не можем по тексту определить, какое оно, и не можем понять, где причина, а где следствие. Это тот редкий пример, когда тире дает нам неоднозначный ответ.