# Что такое интонация?

Tags: интонация

Я заметила, что постановка знаков препинания в БСП регламентируется **большим количеством** правил, но при этом мы далеко не всегда получаем чёткий ответ на вопрос, какой знак препинания нужно выбрать **(а их всего-то три знака!**).

В то же время даже в школьных учебниках указано, что "смысловые отношения в БСП выражаются **в устной речи ИНТОНАЦИЕЙ, а на  письме различными знаками препинания**"(Русский язык, 9 класс, 1999 год).

Следует ли из этого, что между ними существует определенное соответствие, которое можно бы использовать в правилах. Вот, к примеру, замена двоеточия тире как-то отражается на интонации и на смысловых отношениях между предложениями? Но в правилах обо этом ничего не говорится.

**И вообще, как она "выглядит", эта интонация: из каких элементов состоит, существуют ли названия для разных видов интонации.** Вот, к примеру, как описать хотя бы перечислительную интонацию (основное средство связи между однородными членами)?

Если нет ответов на эти вопросы или если они есть, но не учитываются в правилах письма, то вряд ли можно разобраться со многими примерами на тему БСП, в том числе с  примером Розенталя про "молодежь, которая ушла из клуба".

Вопрос: [Причино-следственные отношения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433592/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Вижу-вижу "Оду..." Датирована сегодня – ваша? Здорово! Легко и по делу.

Comment: Спасибо, моя. Вы вдохновили... Вспомнились описания средневековых земель – везде глухие леса, но светятся огни монастырей, люди хранят духовную культуру. Как могут, так и хранят – пример для подражания.

Answer (score 1):

```
какой знак препинания нужно выбрать (а их всего-то три знака!)
```

Почему три? Их четыре: запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие, тире.

```
как она "выглядит", эта интонация: из каких элементов 
состоит, существуют ли названия для разных видов интонации.
```

Интонация - средство связи в БСП, состоит она из фразового ударения и повышения и понижения голоса. Есть у неё и названия, правда в разных классификациях несколько отличающиеся:  перечислительная, предупредительная, пояснительная, результативно-следственная и сопоставительная.

Перечислительная интонация при соединительных отношениях между частями БСП

Запятая меду частями БСП:

- части БСП обозначают одновременность или последовательность событий,
- тесно связаны между собой по смыслу,
- обычно кратки,
- произносятся тоном перечисления,
- ! между частями БСП мысленно можно поставить соединительный союз И.

Нужда скачет, нужда пляшет, нужда песенки поет.  [  ], [  ], [  ]. БСП

Точка с запятой между частями БСП:

- части БСП менее связаны по смыслу,
- более распространены,
- содержат собственные знаки,
- к концу предложения голос понижается, возникает пауза.

Сел да поехал; ах, хорошо!  [=  да =]; [межд.,=  ]!

Пояснительная и предупредительная интонация при причинно-пояснительных отношениях между частями/ БСП - двоеточие.

Сопоставительная и результативно-следственная интонация при противопоставлении, сравнении, времени, условии и следствии  - тире.

Образец синтаксического разбора

*Действие человека мгновенно и одно — действие книги множественно и повсеместно. (А. Пушкин.)*

Устный разбор

Предложение повествовательное, невосклицательное. Состоит из двух простых предложений. В первом грамматическая основа — действие человека мгновенно и одно, во втором — действие книги множественно и повсеместно.

Связь между простыми предложениями бессоюзная; средство связи — интонация.

Отношения между простыми предложениями в сложном сопоставительные. **Интонация сопоставления; одинаковые по силе ударения на наиболее важных для противопоставления словах в первой части: мгновенно и одно; во второй: множественно и повсеместно. Первая часть заканчивается небольшим повышением голоса (интонация незаконченности) и паузой; вторая — соответствующим понижением.**

[§ 36. Синтаксический и пунктуационный разбор бессоюзного сложного предложения | tepka.ru](http://www.tepka.ru/russkij_yazyk_9/36.html)

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, за ответ. Знаете, к сожалению, все  разборы, в том числе интонационные,  существуют сами по себе, они не помогают ставить знаки препинания, не упоминаются в официальных правилах, по которым мы работаем. Вот ваш пример: это БСП, отношение противопоставления (можно вставить союз А), интонация разделительная (восходяще-нисходящая), однозначно соответствует разделительному тире. Вот это помощь для постановки знаков препинания. А ведь есть еще тире другое (присоединительное), интонация нисходяще-нисходящая.

Comment: А в правилах эти тире не различаются, отсюда и следует вопросы от людей, которые хотят разобраться, да только литературы для этого нет.  Наша система интонация могла бы иметь интонационное описание по схеме "обобщенное смысловое отношение между  частями предложения - соответствующая интонация - соответствующий знак". Таких схем может быть всего несколько, а у нас вместо этого десятки правил, не дающих однозначного решения. Не знаю,  можно ли что-то изменить в ближайшем будущем,   к сожалению, люди не готовы понять и принять это. Еще раз спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Интонационный разбор в 9 классе есть, и схемы зависимости знаков препинания от интонации есть, а правила пунктуации зависят от структуры, интонации и смысла, а не только от интонации, характер (смысл) отношений между содержанием предложений всё-таки в приоритете, и детям это более ясно, поэтому правила и основываются на содержании, а соответствующая содержанию интонация анализируется устно. Если всё это писать при разборе - это сильно усложнит его.